# Poligonos en OpenLayers (Primer polígono no genera marcador ni label)

Tags: javascript, es6, openlayers

Estoy generando polígonos en un Mapa de OpenLayers, la información la obtengo de una base de datos.

El problema que tengo es que los valores en números sobre cada polígono se corren y no corresponden al polígono.

Los valores deberían quedar así:

Coordenada1=CC1=2740301
Coordenada2=CC1=2740306
Coordenada3=CC1=2740304
Coordenada4=CC1=2740302

[image: Poligono]

Y en el primer poligono no me sale el marcador, no se si desde ahí proviene el problema. Ahora bien en cada marcador hay un evento clic que muestra el número, ahí si aparece bien el valor. Aunque en el snippet no se porque no me funciona.

**UPDATE: Al revisar me di cuenta, que aunque genere los polígonos en distinto orden, el primer polígono jamás muestra ni el valor ni el marcador. Ahí esta el problema y no logro saber porque me pasa eso.**

[image: Error]

https://jsfiddle.net/fs1j4kog/2/

Si alguien puede ayudarme a encontrar mi error muchas gracias.

```js
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({});

var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({});

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [iconFeature]
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({ /*layer con los poligonos*/
  source: new ol.source.Vector()
})

function crearMarcadores(centroPoligono, CentroCosto) {

  var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(centroPoligono),
    name: CentroCosto
  });

  vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);

  iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

  //------------start creation popup
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute("id", CentroCosto);
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  var element = document.getElementById(CentroCosto);
  var popup = new ol.Overlay({
    element: element,
    positioning: 'bottom-center',
    stopEvent: false
  });
  map.addOverlay(popup);

  //------------end creation popup

  // --------------display popup on click
  map.on('click', function(evt) {
    console.log("Click");
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
      });
    console.log("name:");
    console.log(feature.get('name'));
    if (feature.get('name') == CentroCosto) {
      var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
      var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
      popup.setPosition(coord);
      $(element).popover({
        'placement': 'top',
        'html': true,
        'content': feature.get('name')
      });
      $(element).popover('show');
    } else {
      $(element).popover('destroy');
    }

  });
  //---------------end display popup on click
} //termina funcion crearMarcadores


function crearPoligonos(coordenada, cc) {

iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      opacity: 0.75,
      src: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/data/icon.png'
    })),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      text: cc,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'white'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'black',
        width: 1
      }),
      offsetX: -30,
      offsetY: 30
    })
  });
  iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);
  
  var coordenadas = coordenada.split(' ') // Separamos por espacio
    .map(function(data) {
      var info = data.split(','), // Separamos por coma
        coord = { // Creamos el obj de coordenada
          lat: parseFloat(info[1]),
          lng: parseFloat(info[0])
        };
      return coord;
    });
  console.log(coordenada);
  var parserJSTS = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();

  var poly = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([coordenadas.map(function(_ref) {
      var lng = _ref.lng,
        lat = _ref.lat;
      return [lng, lat];
    })])
  });

  var boundingBox = poly.getGeometry().getExtent()
  var polybbox = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(boundingBox)
  })

  var [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax] = boundingBox

  var porcentajin = 0.7 //De este porcentaje depende cuanto se llena del poligono

  var newXmax = xmin + ((xmax - xmin) * porcentajin)

  var newBoundingBox = [xmin, ymin, newXmax, ymax]

  var polybbox50 = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(newBoundingBox)
  })

  var polybbox50jsts = parserJSTS.read(polybbox50.getGeometry())

  var polyjsts = parserJSTS.read(poly.getGeometry())

  var intersectionJSTSGeometry = polyjsts.intersection(polybbox50jsts)

  var intersectionGeometry = parserJSTS.write(intersectionJSTSGeometry)

  var newPoly = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: intersectionGeometry
  })

  newPoly.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: '#02ABFF'
    })
  }))

  //Descomentar para ver los bounding boxes
  //layer.getSource().addFeature(polybbox)
  //layer.getSource().addFeature(polybbox50)
  layer.getSource().addFeature(poly)
  layer.getSource().addFeature(newPoly)

  var centro = ol.extent.getCenter(boundingBox);
  console.log("Centro:");
  console.log(centro);
  console.log(cc);
  crearMarcadores(centro, cc);

  /*iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon( ({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      opacity: 0.75,
      src: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/data/icon.png'
    })),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      text: cc,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'white'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'black',
        width: 1
      }),
      offsetX: -30,
      offsetY: 30
    })
  });
  iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);*/
}

function errores(msg) {
  alert('Error: ' + msg.responseText);
}
//------------start creation map
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
        key: 'AudCyoI6al0eAZmQhwmI1IG9AOdGH8DHHk6PsiGta1faEACulxawFU9KV-XAvZ8f',
        imagerySet: 'AerialWithLabels'
      })
    }),
    layer, vectorLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-90.833434, 13.990260],
    zoom: 14,
    projection: 'EPSG:4326'
  })
});
// --------------end creation map

//generar mapas-------------------------------
function generarMapas() {
  coordenadas1 = '-90.833910,13.994037 -90.833918,13.994095 -90.833924,13.994152 -90.833930,13.994207 -90.833936,13.994263 -90.833943,13.994322 -90.833951,13.994382 -90.833959,13.994440 -90.833965,13.994494 -90.833971,13.994548 -90.833978,13.994608 -90.833984,13.994671 -90.833993,13.994741 -90.834001,13.994811 -90.834010,13.994877 -90.834019,13.994940 -90.834028,13.995003 -90.834036,13.995060 -90.834044,13.995110 -90.834052,13.995162 -90.834061,13.995222 -90.834067,13.995281 -90.834074,13.995336 -90.834080,13.995390 -90.834086,13.995442 -90.834092,13.995495 -90.834100,13.995553 -90.834105,13.995610 -90.834110,13.995665 -90.834116,13.995718 -90.834122,13.995769 -90.834127,13.995820 -90.834134,13.995871 -90.834141,13.995924 -90.834146,13.995974 -90.834149,13.996008 -90.834192,13.996161 -90.834732,13.996091 -90.835519,13.995989 -90.836038,13.995931 -90.836696,13.995846 -90.836677,13.995819 -90.836660,13.995674 -90.836610,13.995123 -90.836480,13.994146 -90.836461,13.994126 -90.836370,13.994036 -90.836287,13.994044 -90.836194,13.994035 -90.836012,13.993789 -90.836003,13.993753 -90.835995,13.993581 -90.836245,13.993529 -90.836375,13.993521 -90.836386,13.993516 -90.836394,13.993512 -90.836394,13.993503 -90.836395,13.993404 -90.836309,13.992635 -90.836266,13.992318 -90.836207,13.991926 -90.836192,13.991927 -90.836170,13.991932 -90.836125,13.991938 -90.836074,13.991943 -90.836010,13.991951 -90.835936,13.991961 -90.835862,13.991968 -90.835791,13.991976 -90.835722,13.991980 -90.835658,13.991985 -90.835597,13.991994 -90.835533,13.992003 -90.835471,13.992011 -90.835408,13.992018 -90.835346,13.992025 -90.835285,13.992033 -90.835228,13.992040 -90.835173,13.992045 -90.835118,13.992051 -90.835062,13.992057 -90.835002,13.992063 -90.834936,13.992071 -90.834868,13.992078 -90.834800,13.992086 -90.834733,13.992094 -90.834663,13.992102 -90.834588,13.992111 -90.834523,13.992120 -90.834474,13.992123 -90.834421,13.992129 -90.834361,13.992133 -90.834298,13.992140 -90.834229,13.992149 -90.834160,13.992161 -90.834092,13.992171 -90.834022,13.992180 -90.833954,13.992185 -90.833889,13.992191 -90.833824,13.992198 -90.833761,13.992205 -90.833709,13.992212 -90.833680,13.992216 -90.833683,13.992242 -90.833693,13.992300 -90.833704,13.992370 -90.833712,13.992445 -90.833720,13.992518 -90.833727,13.992591 -90.833736,13.992661 -90.833745,13.992730 -90.833755,13.992795 -90.833764,13.992855 -90.833772,13.992913 -90.833779,13.992971 -90.833786,13.993033 -90.833792,13.993092 -90.833799,13.993149 -90.833807,13.993202 -90.833815,13.993251 -90.833823,13.993302 -90.833830,13.993358 -90.833837,13.993410 -90.833843,13.993462 -90.833849,13.993518 -90.833857,13.993579 -90.833864,13.993641 -90.833870,13.993700 -90.833876,13.993760 -90.833881,13.993817 -90.833887,13.993871 -90.833894,13.993927 -90.833902,13.993982 -90.833910,13.994037';

  coordenadas2 = '-90.833434,13.990260 -90.833444,13.990321 -90.833452,13.990383 -90.833461,13.990446 -90.833470,13.990509 -90.833479,13.990572 -90.833486,13.990635 -90.833494,13.990697 -90.833501,13.990760 -90.833510,13.990823 -90.833520,13.990886 -90.833530,13.990948 -90.833538,13.991006 -90.833545,13.991061 -90.833552,13.991112 -90.833557,13.991165 -90.833561,13.991220 -90.833567,13.991282 -90.833572,13.991348 -90.833580,13.991414 -90.833587,13.991476 -90.833593,13.991536 -90.833601,13.991597 -90.833608,13.991662 -90.833617,13.991727 -90.833627,13.991790 -90.833633,13.991853 -90.833640,13.991914 -90.833648,13.991972 -90.833654,13.992029 -90.833661,13.992086 -90.833668,13.992140 -90.833673,13.992172 -90.833702,13.992167 -90.833755,13.992160 -90.833819,13.992153 -90.833884,13.992146 -90.833950,13.992140 -90.834017,13.992135 -90.834085,13.992127 -90.834153,13.992116 -90.834222,13.992105 -90.834292,13.992095 -90.834356,13.992088 -90.834417,13.992084 -90.834470,13.992078 -90.834518,13.992075 -90.834582,13.992066 -90.834658,13.992058 -90.834727,13.992049 -90.834795,13.992041 -90.834863,13.992034 -90.834931,13.992027 -90.834996,13.992018 -90.835057,13.992012 -90.835114,13.992006 -90.835168,13.992000 -90.835223,13.991995 -90.835280,13.991988 -90.835340,13.991981 -90.835403,13.991973 -90.835465,13.991966 -90.835527,13.991958 -90.835590,13.991949 -90.835653,13.991940 -90.835718,13.991935 -90.835787,13.991931 -90.835857,13.991923 -90.835930,13.991916 -90.836003,13.991906 -90.836068,13.991898 -90.836120,13.991893 -90.836162,13.991887 -90.836187,13.991882 -90.836204,13.991875 -90.836197,13.991794 -90.836145,13.991395 -90.836119,13.991187 -90.836033,13.990464 -90.835948,13.989722 -90.835879,13.989197 -90.835811,13.988582 -90.835741,13.988067 -90.835732,13.988048 -90.835714,13.988048 -90.835371,13.988126 -90.834888,13.988240 -90.834481,13.988308 -90.834036,13.988350 -90.833573,13.988409 -90.833208,13.988448 -90.833210,13.988464 -90.833219,13.988531 -90.833229,13.988598 -90.833236,13.988664 -90.833244,13.988729 -90.833251,13.988790 -90.833258,13.988849 -90.833264,13.988906 -90.833270,13.988964 -90.833278,13.989023 -90.833288,13.989081 -90.833295,13.989133 -90.833301,13.989185 -90.833307,13.989231 -90.833315,13.989282 -90.833321,13.989336 -90.833327,13.989388 -90.833332,13.989440 -90.833339,13.989494 -90.833348,13.989551 -90.833354,13.989613 -90.833361,13.989674 -90.833369,13.989737 -90.833378,13.989800 -90.833386,13.989863 -90.833393,13.989926 -90.833399,13.989988 -90.833408,13.990049 -90.833415,13.990102 -90.833422,13.990155 -90.833427,13.990208 -90.833429,13.990227 -90.833432,13.990221 -90.833439,13.990218 -90.833445,13.990221 -90.833448,13.990227 -90.833445,13.990233 -90.833440,13.990236 -90.833433,13.990235 -90.833430,13.990230 -90.833434,13.990260';

  coordenadas3 = '-90.832897,13.988475 -90.832609,13.988518 -90.832313,13.988560 -90.831989,13.988602 -90.831516,13.988661 -90.831053,13.988720 -90.830599,13.988780 -90.830545,13.988793 -90.830547,13.988811 -90.830552,13.988849 -90.830557,13.988886 -90.830563,13.988926 -90.830569,13.988968 -90.830575,13.989010 -90.830582,13.989052 -90.830588,13.989092 -90.830593,13.989132 -90.830598,13.989173 -90.830605,13.989216 -90.830610,13.989257 -90.830616,13.989298 -90.830622,13.989341 -90.830628,13.989385 -90.830634,13.989431 -90.830640,13.989474 -90.830646,13.989517 -90.830654,13.989561 -90.830662,13.989607 -90.830670,13.989651 -90.830677,13.989692 -90.830684,13.989732 -90.830691,13.989774 -90.830697,13.989819 -90.830703,13.989863 -90.830709,13.989903 -90.830715,13.989945 -90.830722,13.989989 -90.830727,13.990031 -90.830733,13.990072 -90.830739,13.990113 -90.830745,13.990153 -90.830752,13.990194 -90.830758,13.990233 -90.830762,13.990268 -90.830767,13.990308 -90.830774,13.990356 -90.830779,13.990398 -90.830783,13.990436 -90.830787,13.990475 -90.830789,13.990515 -90.830793,13.990559 -90.830797,13.990600 -90.830802,13.990639 -90.830807,13.990680 -90.830813,13.990723 -90.830820,13.990768 -90.830826,13.990818 -90.830832,13.990868 -90.830839,13.990921 -90.830846,13.990976 -90.830853,13.991032 -90.830862,13.991089 -90.830869,13.991147 -90.830878,13.991208 -90.830883,13.991271 -90.830890,13.991334 -90.830901,13.991393 -90.830912,13.991453 -90.830920,13.991509 -90.830927,13.991560 -90.830937,13.991615 -90.830947,13.991684 -90.830957,13.991751 -90.830965,13.991806 -90.830970,13.991852 -90.830978,13.991898 -90.830987,13.991951 -90.830995,13.992004 -90.831004,13.992060 -90.831012,13.992112 -90.831019,13.992163 -90.831029,13.992218 -90.831039,13.992278 -90.831048,13.992334 -90.831055,13.992389 -90.831062,13.992444 -90.831069,13.992497 -90.831069,13.992500 -90.831099,13.992493 -90.831143,13.992483 -90.831190,13.992476 -90.831240,13.992471 -90.831285,13.992467 -90.831330,13.992463 -90.831381,13.992456 -90.831435,13.992449 -90.831488,13.992444 -90.831540,13.992437 -90.831594,13.992430 -90.831649,13.992424 -90.831703,13.992419 -90.831757,13.992414 -90.831811,13.992407 -90.831866,13.992400 -90.831919,13.992394 -90.831974,13.992387 -90.832032,13.992383 -90.832090,13.992379 -90.832146,13.992371 -90.832204,13.992362 -90.832274,13.992351 -90.832348,13.992340 -90.832412,13.992331 -90.832469,13.992325 -90.832522,13.992320 -90.832583,13.992314 -90.832647,13.992303 -90.832713,13.992295 -90.832779,13.992289 -90.832840,13.992283 -90.832901,13.992278 -90.832964,13.992270 -90.833029,13.992263 -90.833090,13.992253 -90.833153,13.992247 -90.833212,13.992241 -90.833260,13.992236 -90.833306,13.992230 -90.833360,13.992222 -90.833413,13.992215 -90.833461,13.992207 -90.833516,13.992196 -90.833569,13.992187 -90.833617,13.992180 -90.833627,13.992178 -90.833622,13.992147 -90.833615,13.992092 -90.833608,13.992034 -90.833602,13.991977 -90.833594,13.991919 -90.833587,13.991858 -90.833581,13.991796 -90.833571,13.991733 -90.833563,13.991667 -90.833555,13.991603 -90.833547,13.991541 -90.833541,13.991481 -90.833534,13.991419 -90.833526,13.991353 -90.833521,13.991285 -90.833515,13.991224 -90.833511,13.991169 -90.833506,13.991117 -90.833499,13.991066 -90.833492,13.991012 -90.833484,13.990955 -90.833474,13.990893 -90.833464,13.990830 -90.833455,13.990765 -90.833448,13.990702 -90.833440,13.990640 -90.833433,13.990578 -90.833424,13.990515 -90.833415,13.990452 -90.833406,13.990389 -90.833398,13.990328 -90.833388,13.990267 -90.833381,13.990213 -90.833375,13.990160 -90.833370,13.990108 -90.833362,13.990055 -90.833353,13.989994 -90.833347,13.989931 -90.833340,13.989868 -90.833332,13.989806 -90.833323,13.989743 -90.833315,13.989680 -90.833308,13.989618 -90.833302,13.989557 -90.833293,13.989500 -90.833286,13.989445 -90.833281,13.989393 -90.833275,13.989341 -90.833269,13.989288 -90.833261,13.989238 -90.833255,13.989190 -90.833249,13.989139 -90.833242,13.989087 -90.833233,13.989030 -90.833224,13.988969 -90.833218,13.988910 -90.833212,13.988854 -90.833205,13.988795 -90.833198,13.988734 -90.833191,13.988670 -90.833183,13.988604 -90.833173,13.988537 -90.833165,13.988471 -90.833162,13.988452 -90.832897,13.988475';

  coordenadas4 = '-90.833577,13.992231 -90.833525,13.992241 -90.833470,13.992251 -90.833420,13.992260 -90.833367,13.992267 -90.833312,13.992275 -90.833266,13.992280 -90.833217,13.992286 -90.833158,13.992291 -90.833097,13.992298 -90.833035,13.992308 -90.832970,13.992315 -90.832906,13.992323 -90.832845,13.992328 -90.832783,13.992334 -90.832718,13.992339 -90.832654,13.992348 -90.832589,13.992358 -90.832527,13.992365 -90.832473,13.992370 -90.832418,13.992376 -90.832355,13.992385 -90.832281,13.992396 -90.832212,13.992406 -90.832153,13.992416 -90.832114,13.992421 -90.832217,13.993235 -90.832124,13.993315 -90.831292,13.993421 -90.831303,13.993471 -90.831313,13.993521 -90.831325,13.993573 -90.831338,13.993629 -90.831352,13.993686 -90.831365,13.993742 -90.831378,13.993797 -90.831393,13.993854 -90.831407,13.993911 -90.831420,13.993966 -90.831435,13.994022 -90.831451,13.994080 -90.831464,13.994137 -90.831477,13.994193 -90.831491,13.994249 -90.831506,13.994307 -90.831521,13.994366 -90.831534,13.994425 -90.831547,13.994481 -90.831558,13.994534 -90.831571,13.994588 -90.831585,13.994644 -90.831598,13.994700 -90.831611,13.994752 -90.831623,13.994804 -90.831635,13.994856 -90.831647,13.994905 -90.831659,13.994953 -90.831671,13.995002 -90.831683,13.995053 -90.831695,13.995105 -90.831707,13.995159 -90.831718,13.995212 -90.831730,13.995261 -90.831742,13.995311 -90.831751,13.995360 -90.831760,13.995409 -90.831769,13.995459 -90.831783,13.995508 -90.831796,13.995557 -90.831808,13.995607 -90.831819,13.995655 -90.831829,13.995700 -90.831839,13.995746 -90.831851,13.995798 -90.831865,13.995852 -90.831880,13.995907 -90.831895,13.995960 -90.831908,13.996007 -90.831921,13.996054 -90.831929,13.996100 -90.831939,13.996144 -90.831951,13.996189 -90.831964,13.996235 -90.831974,13.996279 -90.832004,13.996404 -90.832165,13.996402 -90.832508,13.996369 -90.832749,13.996335 -90.832879,13.996318 -90.833536,13.996234 -90.833694,13.996217 -90.833722,13.996208 -90.834097,13.996166 -90.834103,13.996011 -90.834100,13.995977 -90.834095,13.995929 -90.834088,13.995877 -90.834082,13.995825 -90.834076,13.995775 -90.834070,13.995723 -90.834064,13.995669 -90.834059,13.995614 -90.834054,13.995558 -90.834046,13.995500 -90.834040,13.995447 -90.834035,13.995395 -90.834028,13.995342 -90.834021,13.995286 -90.834015,13.995228 -90.834006,13.995168 -90.833999,13.995117 -90.833990,13.995067 -90.833982,13.995009 -90.833973,13.994946 -90.833964,13.994883 -90.833955,13.994816 -90.833947,13.994747 -90.833938,13.994676 -90.833932,13.994613 -90.833925,13.994553 -90.833919,13.994498 -90.833913,13.994445 -90.833905,13.994388 -90.833897,13.994328 -90.833890,13.994268 -90.833884,13.994212 -90.833878,13.994156 -90.833872,13.994100 -90.833864,13.994044 -90.833856,13.993988 -90.833848,13.993933 -90.833841,13.993876 -90.833835,13.993821 -90.833830,13.993764 -90.833824,13.993705 -90.833818,13.993645 -90.833811,13.993584 -90.833803,13.993523 -90.833797,13.993467 -90.833791,13.993416 -90.833784,13.993363 -90.833778,13.993309 -90.833769,13.993258 -90.833761,13.993208 -90.833753,13.993155 -90.833746,13.993097 -90.833740,13.993037 -90.833733,13.992976 -90.833726,13.992918 -90.833718,13.992862 -90.833709,13.992801 -90.833699,13.992736 -90.833690,13.992667 -90.833681,13.992596 -90.833674,13.992522 -90.833666,13.992450 -90.833658,13.992376 -90.833648,13.992307 -90.833638,13.992249 -90.833634,13.992223 -90.833577,13.992231';

  cc1 = "2740301";
  cc2 = "2740306";
  cc3 = "2740304";
  cc4 = "2740302";


  crearPoligonos(coordenadas3, cc3);
  crearPoligonos(coordenadas4, cc4);
  crearPoligonos(coordenadas1, cc1);
  crearPoligonos(coordenadas2, cc2);
}
//finaliza generar mapas----------------------------

$(document).ready(function() {
  generarMapas();
});
```

```css
        .btn-info {
          margin-top: 10px;
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #5bc0de;
          border-color: #46b8da;
          width: 97px;
          height: 33px;
        }
        
        #map {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
        
        html,
        body {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
        
        #map {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0px;
          right: 0px;
        }
        
        .navbar-xs {
          min-height: 22px;
          border-radius: 0;
          z-index: 15;
        }
        
        .navbar-xs .navbar-brand {
          padding: 2px 8px;
          font-size: 14px;
          line-height: 14px;
          z-index: 15;
        }
        
        .navbar-xs .navbar-nav > li > a {
          border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
          z-index: 15;
        }
        
        .btn-primary {
          background-color: #3c8dbc;
          border-color: #367fa9;
          margin-left: 10px;
          margin-top: 10px;
        }
        
        .form-control {
          margin-top: 10px;
          width: 100% !important;
        }
        
        label {
          margin-top: 15px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsts/1.5.0/jsts.js"></script>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/build/ol-debug.js"></script>
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="map">
</div>
<div id="popup">
</div>
```

Comment: Veo muchos "fallos" en tu código que tienen que ver un poco con la organización. El principal problema por el que no se te muestra el primero es: Inicializas como variables globales `iconFeature` e `iconStyle` como feature vacía y estlo vacío. Luego si te fijas en crearPoligonos `iconFeture` apunta a la variable global vacía. Y en `crearMarcadores`, `iconStyle` la primera vez apunta al estilo vacío y luego se va sobreescribiendo.

Comment: Es posible que me puedas ayudar a resolverlos, por favor.

Comment: Con lo que me indicaste, pude resolver el problema del marcador y el texto.  Ahora los demás fallos no he logrado todavía.

Comment: Me alegro. Pues lo que te recomiendo es que organices el código. Otra recomendación es que no crees un `.on('click,...)` para cada marcador. Haz un manejador global.

Comment: Buenas tardes Jose, disculpa la molestia como se hace para limpiar el mapa de todos los polígonos que he generado? Es que aunque ejecuto la busqueda no limpia el poligono que se creó en una anterior busqueda. Gracias.

Comment: `layer.getSource().clear()`